# How to extract data from webpage from child class or subclasses with help of VBA

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

```
<ul class="item-amenities">
  <li><span class="icon-bed"></span> 2 </li>

  <li><span class="icon-bath"></span> 3 </li>

  <li><span class="icon-area_3"></span> 1,014 sq. ft.</li>
</ul>
```

`item-amenities` is a child class, I am able to extract `Item-amenities` whole in single cell but I need `Icon Bed` to go in a different cell, `Icon Bath` to go in a different cell etc.

I used the code below:

```
Case "item-amenities"

sht.Range("B" & RowCount + 1) = obj.innerText
```

Comment: You should explain your problem more and also what you have tried. Most of the time you need to add your code to let people understand your problem and be able to help you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Make sure to use the code blocks function of the text editor to properly format your code in future.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this...

This creates an object called iconAmenities which contains all of the html objects in `<ul class="item-amenities">`. Then you cycle through each child object with the `For Each` statement and extract the `innnerText`.

```
Set itemAmenities = htmlObject.getElementsByClassName("item-amenities")

For Each icon In itemAmenities
    iconValue = icon.innerText

    <<insert iconValue into relevant cell>>

Next icon
```

Of course you would declare all of the above variables / objects prior to using them. This also assumes you have already created the `htmlObject` previously.

Comment: Thanks Porupine, Michael, & Del
Guy could pls check this link have attatched the full code and link for webiste
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35719082/how-to-extract-data-from-webpage-from-child-class-or-subclasses-with-help-of-vba